# Bigrock windows hosting error MVC Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have recently hosted a mvc 4 application in big rock hosting environment.

I am getting the following error.
**HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.**

The server internal log file shows that it is  trying to search for some index file, but asp .net mvc doesn't have specific index files.

url - [www.ekartdeals.com](http://www.ekartdeals.com)

```
Server Internal Log
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<config><domain name="ekartdeals.com" logs_directory="---REMOVED ---" webspaceName="ekartdeals.com" default_doc="Index.html 
Index.htm 
Index.cfm 
Index.shtml 
Index.shtm 
Index.stm 
Index.php 
Index.php3 
Index.asp 
Index.aspx 
Default.htm 
Default.asp 
Default.aspx"><webstat type="awstats"/><alias name="ekartdeals.com"/><alias name="www.ekartdeals.com"/></domain></config>
```

Comment: Ya I found and fixed the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the root cause of this issue.

1. Big rock ASP .NET version was pointing to v2.0 so I had to change it to version 4.0
2. The MVC Application was developed in v4.5 so had to change the published version to .net framework v4.0

After making the changes it worked fine.

Comment: agree with these changes cs I was facing this issues during my MVC application launch!!